# different auto-configuration for prod and test?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, dependency-injection

I'm working on a library for Spring Boot. Currently, it has some auto-configuration for production.

Now, I'd like to also (as a library) to supply mock classes, *instead* of the regular ones, for unit tests.

I know that Spring Batch does that by marking the test class with `@SpringBatchTest`.

How can I achieve a similar behaviour?

Comment: `ConditionalOn` classes can help you achive that behaviour.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to understand if that correct class is `ConditionalOnClass`

Comment: There are many of them for different usecases.

Answer (score 1):

The mock classes or test support classes should be provided in separate library. This is the approach followed be spring team. 
 Having tests support classes packaged together with production classes is antipatern and should be avoided.

Comment: OK. Suppose I do that. How do I achieve the behaviour I described?

Comment: You will provide your test configuration similar to what `spring-boot-test-autoconfigure` does for all layers. See `spring.factories` from `spring-boot-test-autoconfigure`  module.
 Another option will be to register @MockBean or @SpyBean  and let users to configure theirs behavior.

Comment: but then Spring will have two candidates for my `@Bean`. How can to solve this? What is my `@ConditionalOn...`?

Comment: There is no conditional on. `@TestXXX` annotation configures your application with this particular configuration. Others are not applied. See how they configure theirs `@JdbcTest` for example.